# is any way to execut the linux command as "exec cat spec.txt | cut -d "|" -f 2" in tclsh

Tags: tcl

I've a spec.txt as below, it's ok to run command of "cat spec.txt | cut -d "|" -f 2" in linux shell.

```
user@test-server:~/auto/acpi6/main/spec$ cat spec.txt
a1 | BMC_HEALTH       | 0x0        | discrete   | 0x0000| na        | na        | na        | na        | na        | na

user@test-server:~/auto/acpi6/main/spec$ cat spec.txt | cut -d "|" -f 2
 BMC_HEALTH
```

-> why it fails to run command of

```
"exec cat spec.txt | cut -d "|" -f 2" in tclsh
% exec cat spec.txt | cut -d "|" -f 2
couldn't execute "-f": no such file or directory
```

Comment: Maybe a problem with the " around | ? Have you tried escaping them? (as in \"|\" )

Comment: Have you considered writing the parse in Tcl  instead of starting a new program?  The pipe character is special to Tcl's exec command and cannot be escaped.

Comment: This is one of the classic tricky cases in `exec`. There is no good way to quote it, and *we know this is a problem*. No nice way to fix it without making other, more common use cases worse, so we keep worrying about it and not fixing it.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that the Tcl standard interpreter rules convert that quoted `|` to an unquoted bare one before `exec` sees it. It is one of the places where Tcl's regular syntax rules (otherwise a very good thing) bite.

The simplest workaround is to use `sh` as an intermediary.

```
exec cat spec.txt | sh -c {exec cut -d "|" -f 2}
```

The part in the braces is in shell syntax, not Tcl, and so can handle this case.